# Gitlab wiki search result shows markdown syntax

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-wiki

Is it possible to **not** return code in gitlab **wiki** search result?

Check the markdown code `**` at the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the GitLab markdown cheat sheet yet?

If I have to guess you might have entered too many asteriks in the markdown text. Here is a GitLab cheat sheet for markdown syntex.

https://gitlab.com/francoisjacquet/rosariosis/-/wikis/Markdown-Cheatsheet

[screenshot for asterik rules for markdowns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtgX5.png)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not the case. Check [this](https://imgur.com/N5d6xIS) print of the wiki article source.